# Failure to turn on list auditing programatically

Tags: 2013, development, ssom, spaudit

I have a `SPListEventReceiver` with a `ListAdded()` override that responds to the creation of Document Libraries. What I am trying to do is turn on auditing for the newly created Document Library like so:

```
SPList list = web.Lists[properties.List.ID];
list.Audit.AuditFlags = SPAuditMaskType.View;
list.Audit.Update();
```

When I go to the list in the UI and look in its `Information management policy settings`, the `Enable Auditing` box isn't ticked. Stepping through the code in debug mode doesn't throw an error either. How do I properly activate auditing on a list?

Comment: If you copy pasted the actual code, then there is a square bracket missing at the end of line 1. SPList list = web.Lists[properties.List.ID];

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis, oops sorry. Not copy/paste, just a typo on my part :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the auditing for every list, why don't you turn it on for the whole site collection?:

```
public static void ActivateAuditing(SPWeb web)
{
    if (web.IsRootWeb == true)
    {
        var site = web.Site;

        AuditLogTrimmingReportCallout.SetAuditReportStorageLocation(site, 
            SPUtility.ConcatUrls(site.ServerRelativeUrl, "/AuditReports"));

        site.TrimAuditLog = true;

        site.Audit.AuditFlags = SPAuditMaskType.View

        site.Audit.Update();      
    }
}
```

In your particular case, you might be missing a one time configuration setting of where to store the audit logs:

```
AuditLogTrimmingReportCallout.SetAuditReportStorageLocation(site, 
                SPUtility.ConcatUrls(site.ServerRelativeUrl, "/AuditReports"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should have specified that the Event Receiver is responding to the creation of Document Libraries not every list (please see edit). Is my code block correct for activating it at the list level?